# Why is the FILE structure from stdio.h written in uppercase?

Tags: c

Why is the name of a `FILE` structure from `stdio.h` written in uppercase?

Comment: While not ? Every alphabetic characeter upper- or lowercase can be used. So why not ?

Comment: This question cannot be definitively answered unless someone involved in the original definition is on SO, or a reference from such a person can be found and cited.

Comment: Still, other structs (even system ones) are often in small_caps_underscored, so one asks why this one is different; or at least I do.

Comment: @EricJ. *unless*. And it is not unrealistic that such a document exists.

Comment: @ouah: Which makes any answer opinion-based and the question subject to closure.

Comment: @EricJ. which makes an answer with an historic reference possible.

Comment: It is possible to make reasonable deductions by examining the evidence available.

Comment: **Not voting to close** as opinion-based: We now have multiple evidence-based answers.  It is clear that this question has a definite answer and is not open to speculation.

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès: I think we can all agree that if a new symbol "hElLoWoRlD" were to appear in the standard library, we'd ask where this case convention came from and why it were used. Type names are generally not all-uppercase in POSIX nor in the C standard library, so this is a perfectly reasonable question.

Comment: I doubt it has any programming interest except that it was probably because `FILE` was primarily an opaque type, but I agreed on the fact that it is an interesting historical question (something like "why `open` is prototyped in `fcntl.h` and `read/write/close` in `unistd.h`?"). Anyway I didn't vote for close.

Comment: You are freely mixing "C" (a programming language) and "Unix" (an operating system). While historically they are strongly connected, you still cannot use them interchangeably. The question is not 'about', or even 'related to', Unix.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The most likely reason was that it was once a `#define`, and `#define`s are conventionally all caps.

Comment: That would make sense, I haven't really thought of that.Thanks!

Comment: Actually, it was a `typedef` at least from the time of K&R 2nd edition, circa 1988.

Comment: Indeed, here's the [32V version of `stdio.h`](https://github.com/dspinellis/unix-history-repo/blob/Bell-Release/usr/include/stdio.h), with a `#define FILE`.

Comment: Possibly C did not have `typedef` at  that time.

Comment: @user3386109 `typedef` also in K&R 1st ed

Comment: @robmayoff, this repo's great! Haven't heard of it before.

Comment: @robmayoff I didn't know this repo, thanks for the link!

Comment: @ouah Both Unix and C predate K&R by several years. [Dennis Ritchie's history of C](https://www.bell-labs.com/usr/dmr/www/chist.pdf), while not mentioning `typedef`, says that the earliest portable I/O package appeared by 1972, and the C language “grew quite a bit” in the years 1973-1980, so it's plausible that stdio predates `typedef`, and we have proof that `FILE` was indeed once a preprocessor macro.

Comment: [Eric Raymond claims](http://www.catb.org/esr/writings/taoup/html/c_evolution.html) that C  got `typedef` in 1976, well after stdio was created, but doesn't offer a citation.

Comment: The prove is here in the UNIX 7 version of `stdio.h`: http://minnie.tuhs.org/cgi-bin/utree.pl?file=V7/usr/include/stdio.h

Answer (score 8):

To summarize what's already been pointed out:

1. UPPER CASE is the convention for C "macros".
2. "FILE" is intended to be an "opaque" structure: you're supposed to use it, but you're not supposed to "known" about it's internals.  Which can (and will) change from platform to platform.

   Specifically:

> http://tigcc.ticalc.org/doc/stdio.html
>
> FILE is the main file control structure for streams. The exact
> structure of it is very platform-dependent, so ANSI C proposes that
> the exact structure of this structured type should not be known, and
> well-written programs do not need to access the internal fields of
> this structure.

3. As alk pointed out above, not only *CAN* "FILE" be implemented as a macro, but in Unix7 it actually *WAS* implemented as a macro:

   http://minnie.tuhs.org/cgi-bin/utree.pl?file=V7/usr/include/stdio.h

V7/usr/include/stdio.h =>

```
#define BUFSIZ  512
#define _NFILE  20
# ifndef FILE
extern  struct  _iobuf {
    char  *_ptr;
    int   _cnt;
    char  *_base;
    char  _flag;
    char  _file;
} _iob[_NFILE];
# endif
...
#define FILE    struct _iobuf
...
```